# Should one salt & hash the response to the challenge question used for lost pw?

Tags: security

If you salt & hash a pw in a db, should you also do so for the response to the challenge question used during a temporary pw generation?

Thanks,

JDelage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the stored response. If you only want to compare it **exactly** to the response supplied by the user, storing it as a salted hash will be fine and is highly recommended.

But if you allow an answer that is almost correct (e.g. case-sensitivity or missed whitespaces), you will need the original string for comparison. Also if you have a helpdesk that supports users resetting their password, you might want them to be able to compare the answers. In such cases you will need the original string, the hash is useless. Your decision depends on what you might need the original string for during the password reset process.

In case you cannot avoid storing the information in clear text, you should enforce additional restrictions to password resets like a validated email address to send an authorization link to, before the password can be changed.

Comment: You should maybe even warn the user that their answer will not be stored securely, as they may use the same question/answer combination on other sites.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you should.

There is no need to ever know what the challenge was, only if it was answered correctly.

Comment: If I offer several questions to be chosen from, surely I should remind the user which question he chose...

Comment: Remembering the question is fine, but the answer should be stored securely.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about password recovery questions & answers, then, good heavens, yes! You might be able to implement a bit more traceability around the processes of password recovery (to detect and prevent attempted cracking), but that part of your database is just as sensitive as your passwords, and would harm your users if leaked in plaintext.

Basically, password recovery challenges are just passwords by another name...